# How to visualize an array as lines in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to visualize an array using lines in pygame but it is drawing random lines on the surface. Here is the code :

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
array = [100, 256, 132, 151, 493]

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
gameDisplay.fill(black)
pygame.display.set_caption("test")

x1 = 0
y1 = 600
x2 = x1

for number in array:
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, white, (x1, y1), (x2, number), 2)
        x1 += 100

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    for number in array:
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, white, (x1, y1), (x2, number), 2)
        x1 += 100
    pygame.display.update()
```

I tried putting the for loop outside the while loop and it is the same thing but not drawing infinitely the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw vertical lines, then the x coordinate of the start and the end of the lies has to be equal).
If the lines are draw in the main loop, then the start coordinates wich progressively incremented (like `x`) have to be initialized inside the loop.

e.g.

```py
y1 = 600
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    x = 0
    for number in array:
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, white, (x, y1), (x, number), 2)
        x += 100
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Oh god thank you I have to debug more my programs that was an obvious problem. Thank you very much.